# .jar files cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10)

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar, playframework-2.1, scala-ide

I am building my first Scala/Play application and after I create and import an eclipse project from the Play shell, I get 17 errors.

akka-actor_2.10.jar is cross compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10)
akka-slf4j_2.10.jar is cross compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10)
anorm_2.10.jar ...
play_2.10.jar ...
play_iterates_2.10.jar ...

The list goes on to include the Scala jars, scalaz jars, etc...

I am using:
 Eclipse 4.2.2
 Scala ide 3.0.0.nightly-2_09
 Scala 2.10
 Play 2.1

Has someone experienced the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure these are errors? I see warnings in project and everything works fine. It's all Play's fault, 2.1 final is compiled with Scala 2.10-RC5.

Comment: Even I am trying to import my first scalatra application and I get lot of incompatibility errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible you are using Scala IDE built for for Scala 2.9.x ?

Make sure you use the one for 2.10.x: 
http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/dev/site/